# How to fix "Extra argument 'at' in call" in swift's playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift-playground

I've got a problem with some code. While I was writing function to define variables in a table I had an "Extra argument 'at' in call" error. I was trying many, many things (including rewritting code from Udemy lesson) and sadly it is not working still.

Here's the code:

```
var tablica = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

func przypisywanie (position: Int) {
   tablica.insert(Int(arc4random() % 49) + 1, at: position ) {
   }
}
```

Thanks

Btw sorry if it is a silly question, but I'm complete beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the extra curly braces:

```
var tablica = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

func przypisywanie (position: Int) {
    tablica.insert(Int(arc4random() % 49) + 1, at: position )
}
```

Comment: I don’t know what “not working” means. The code in my answer compiles without error.